# current_user changing value in flask

Tags: python, flask

I am new to flask so please forgive me if my code is lousy and try to give corrections.
I am trying to implement a login using flask-login in my app. When I login `current_user` is shown as `<user "nickname">`, but after a refresh it shows as anonymous.

Here is what I think is the relevant code in my views file.

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data).first()
        if form.validate_on_submit():       
            if user is None:
                user = User(name=form.name.data,email=form.email.data,password=form.password.data) 
                db.session.add(user)
                db.session.commit()
                login_user(user,remember=True)
                return redirect(url_for('index'))
            else:
                user=User(name=form.name.data,password=form.password.data,email=form.email.data)
                if True #eventually this will check whether the password you inputted matches the password associated with the email you inputted:
                    login_user(user,remember=True)
    return render_template('login.html', form=form,)

@app.route("/logout")
@login_required
def logout():
    logout_user()
    return redirect(url_for("index"))

@app.before_request
def before_request():
    g.user = current_user
```

I've had a good search for the answer so I think the problem is with my system for logging in users not actually the `current_user`.
Thanks in advance

EDIT:
The problem turned out to be that my `get_id` function was returning `self.id`, which did not exist. I made it return `self.email`, and all was fine.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that if you don't find the existing User, you're creating a user object  but not calling the following to add them to the database:

```
db.session.add(user)
db.session.commit()
```

This would explain why, on the page refresh, you lose the information about the user.

Also, you're checking `if form.validate_on_submit():` twice, but this only needs to be checked once.

Comment: @matthealey do you mean in the else clause of if user is None.?

Comment: If i put that in I get an error because the email has to be unique in my database. Should I delete the user first then add them again each time?

Comment: yes, you might have to do that. At the moment you are generating a user object and logging that user in, but not saving the user to the database, so on the next page load you lose that user.

Comment: How would I delete the user?

Comment: I'm not sure, it depends what database you're using. Alternatively you could implement the code to actually check that the user's password is correct. For now, I recommend you just remove the line where you create the user object after your "else" statement. There is no need to be creating it when you've already got a user object from your initial query.